# Whats the best IT Security Web Forum?

Tags: professional-education

I'm looking for a good source for IT Security, specifically information for Information Security Professionals. I'm wondering what your favorite is?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Especially Boaz Tirosh...kudos!

Answer (score 5):

Simple: the one you're on right now.

Comment: But this isn't a forum, it's a Q&A engine1!11

Comment: Yep, exactly right

Answer (score 1):

I don't rely on just one website, but rather a collection there of.

I recommend using google reader to pull multiple feeds.

This will help you get started: http://www.google.com/reader/bundle/user%2F03471370118315696004%2Fbundle%2FSecurity